# "Unhandled Activation Error" after resynchronizing Xamarin license

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, enterprise

I need to build cross-platform apps with Xamarin for my internship. I just installed the Enterprise 2015 edition of Visual Studio on my Windows 10 laptop. I also set Xamarin Studio on my Mac mini.

After successfully running a basic iPhone "HelloiOS" app with the Mac host, I tried running a basic Xamarin.Forms "HelloWorld" app with the Mac host. However, I ran into a User Code Size error suggesting me to upgrade to a Business edition (or higher). I checked my Xamarin Account under the Tools tab in Visual Studio and saw that I was indeed logged in under my account with the trial Visual Studio Enterprise. I then attempted to resynchronize my account and followed the "Extended manual license refresh steps" protocol in the following link: https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1641743-manually-resynchronize-xamarin-licenses.

When attempting to log back into my account in step 6, I got the following error in the image [Error from attempted account resynchronize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGQ4x.png).

I need to not only fix this error, but also set up my account in a way that I can test/debug apps in Xamarin.Forms with my Mac host using my account with the trial of Visual Studio Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into the code size limitation, then it is likely you are running an old version of Xamarin (i.e., before the launch of the free community version).

Before doing anything else, try updating to the latest version:

Visual Studio: Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other -> Check now

To use the community edition, you should not need to log in with a Xamarin account.

If you continue to have problems with this after updating, please reach out to us at contact@xamarin.com and we can help you out with license and activation issues.